# When I download my validly codesigned app from a browser, it says it's damaged

Tags: macos, code-signing, electron

I have a Mac OSX electron app that I use electron-builder to sign. My certificate is valid and doesn't expire until 2020. When I build my app's .app and .dmg files and I run `spctl --assess --verbose MyApp.app/`, it says "accepted". When I download either the dmg or a zip file containing the .app from a browser and run it, a dialog comes and says this app is damaged with an option to move it to the trash. Previously released versions of my app that had no such problem are now throwing this error, despite still passing `spctl -a` locally. `codesign --verify --verbose MyApp.app/` also says it's valid. Also if I run the app locally, it doesn't throw those errors.

What's happening here?

Comment: What's your setting in System Preferences->Security & Privacy->General for "Allow apps downloaded from"?

Comment: @PhillipMills "Mac App Store and identified developers". When I run the `spctl` command it returns "MyApp.app/: accepted source=Developer ID", so I assume I'm an "identified developer".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A nested app dependency was changed somehow changed after the signing which invalidates the signature. To check for this, you have to run `codesign --verify --deep MyApp.app/`. The `--deep` flag recurses through nested dependencies and verifies them.

The reason downloading the app from the internet will trigger Gatekeeper security checks that won't happen otherwise. For electron apps using electron-builder, deep codesign verification has been added, see details here: https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-osx-sign/issues/42.